# Reading variable length/types row in Fortran

Tags: io, fortran, fortran90

I have a row of data in fortran, and I need to read in the different values. The number of values can be anything, and the type as well. Examples

```
0.45 1 T F
```

or

```
0.45 1 T 2.45 18.0 45.2
```

how can I read successfully this row, or at least decompose it in its fundamentals tokens, without fetching the next line information (this must be prevented at all costs).

Answer (score 4):

You can read the entire row into a variable of type character, then you do whatever you want with the character variable, then read the next row and so forth.

Comment: You do a regular read of the rwo into a character variable.   You can then read from the character variable (which is called "internal IO") using whatever logic is necessary to decide which particular items were on that row.   Or parse the character variable without using IO.